# Как удалить строку из динамического массива?

Tags: c, массивы, динамические-массивы

Требуется создать двумерный массив (выделив для него память динамически), заполнить его некоторыми данными, затем проверить каждую строку на соответствие некоему условию (`RepeatTwo(i,m) == 1 && downsimple(i,m) == 1`, где i - номер строки, m - длина строки) и, при истинности этого условия, удалить данную строку. Нижеприведенный код работает некорректно, а именно, не удаляет/неправильно удаляет выбранные строки. Помогите найти ошибку/ошибки в коде.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <locale.h>
int **a;

void matrix(int n,int m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("RepeatTwo = %d, DownSimple = %d\n",RepeatTwo(i,m) == 1 ,downsimple(i,m));
        if(RepeatTwo(i,m) == 1 && downsimple(i,m) == 1)
        {
            printf("Delete this str\n");
            free(a[i]);

        }

    }

}

int main()
{
    int n,m,i,j;

    printf("The NUMBER of N:\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);


    printf("The NUMBER of M:\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    a = (int**)malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        a[i] = (int*)malloc(m*sizeof(int));
            for(j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
     }



    matrix(n,m);
    free(a);
    printf("\n\nMemory free!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Код с примером тестового ввода здесь:
http://ideone.com/w5p0XR

Вот результат, которого я хочу добиться:
Исходные данные (1-я и 3-я строки удовлетворяет описанному условию)

```
    18 25 4 4 4
    7 8 9 10 11
    1 3 3 4 5
    11 23 13 14 15
```

Результат:

```
7 8 9 10 11
11 23 13 14 15
```

Comment: free(), насколько я помню, не обязана заполнять освобожденную память нулями. Память помечается освобожденной, но ее прежнее содержимое может оставаться.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Что такое RepeatTwo и downsimple?

Comment: Какие симолы там же int? Или поясните.

Comment: В чем проявляется неудаление строки, а только пары символов?

Comment: Есть матрица, её объявления вы видите. Нужно удалить n-ю строку из неё. А потом его вывести. Вот если удалить, там мусор, потом выводишь - выводиться мусор - всё ок. НО. Если матрицу распечатать в лоб, вместе с мусором - то видно что не все элементы строки удалились.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Приведите эту распечатку, что там за мусор. Что вы понимаете под удалением в таком случае, в чем оно должно проявляться, то есть какого поведения вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, я вот тоже не понимаю, что значит "удаление строки из динамического массива". Ничего похожего, на то, что я могу ожидать от процедуры с таким названием, Ваш код не делает. Вы освобождаете память, на которую указывает указатель `a[i]`. При этом само значение указателя не меняется (см описание функции free). Что там лежит в этой области памяти после исполнения `free` никому не известно и известно быть не может.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, функции.

Comment: @Cerbo, опечатался, исправил. Удалить строку и расчпечатать без неё.
Можно конечно записать индекс этой строки и просто её не печатать, но разве нельзя удалить строку из динамического массива(т.е. сделать массив размером n-1), получить его новые размеры и напечатать. Сейчас закину код на ideone

Comment: Чего вы пытаетесь добиться, оскорбляя читателей?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, призываю думать.   Проблему, благодаря замечанию в ответе уже решил. Сейчас доисправлю и напишу в комментариях чуть подробнее. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы написал Вашу функцию `matrix` так:

```
int matrix(int n,int m) // функция возвращает новое к-во строк
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(some_condition(a[i], m))
        {
            printf("Delete this str\n");
            --n; // уменьшаем к-во строк
            int *temp = a[i]; // "запоминаем" указатель на "ненужную" строку
            for(int j=i; j<n; j++) // сдвигаем строки "вверх"
                a[j] = a[j+1]; // просто меняем значение указателя на строку
            a[n] = NULL; // дабы не было соблазна использовать "лишние" строки
            free(temp); // освобождаем память, выделенную для "ненужной" строки
        }
    }
    return n; // возвращаем оставшееся количество строк
}
```

Ну, и сами данные `a` лучше передать еще одним аргументом в функцию, дабы не плодить глобальные переменные.

Comment: Была ошибка, поправил.

Answer (score 0):

Функция `free` необязана занулять либо иным способом очищать освобождаемый блок памяти. По стандарту, при обращении по адресу уже освобожденного блока, поведение не определенно, то есть по-простому запрещено. Посему чтобы этого избежать следует занулять освобожденный указатель:

```
{
   free(a[i]);
   a[i] = NULL;
}
```

После этого при обращении к нужной строке, вам понадобится проверять не равен ли ее указатель `NULL`.

И еще, просто `free(a)` недостаточно, нужно перед выходом каждую "живую" строку удалить:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
   if(a[i])
   {
      free(a[i]);
      a[i] = NULL;
   }
}
free(a);
```

Comment: посмотрите код на ideone. Там правда есть отладочные принты, но суть понятнее.

Comment: @ВладиславМСК Опишите нормально чего вы хотите получить, то что вы делаете динамическим массивом не является

Comment: @ВладиславМСК, переформулируйте вопрос более понятно, я уже набросал типа рабочий код, но ответить не успел.

Comment: @andy.37, отредактировал вопрос, но не знаю почему он висит в статусе требует правки.